# How to justify text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many string in my array

```
const arr = ["Hello my name is jimmy", "will you go to the cinema with me?", "who's him?"]
```

and I want to retrieve the string from the array and put it on my list, so I do loop it first, but I want to make the text justify, because I have set the max width of my list `eg: 100px`

```
<span style="width: 100px" id="hello">
</span>

arr.forEach(e => {
   const str1 = e.substr(0,10)
   const str2 = e.substr(10) 
   $('#hello').append(str1 + '\n' + str2 + '\n')
})
```

the result that I got from this code is

```
Hello my n
ame is jimmy
will you g
o to the cinema with me?
who's him?
(white space)
```

but I expect to get like this:

```
Hello my
name is jimmy
will you 
go to the cinema with me?
who's him?
(white space)
```

how to make it dynamic? `(not static)`

Comment: I guess you are not looking for justified text but for an intelligent way of splitting your text?

Comment: I have thought about splitting the text by using `space` but I think it twice that I can't split it by `space` because I think every string in array have different length of text and different length of space @void

Comment: why are you taking sub string

Comment: I don't have any idea to use split or others. Do you know what is the best way to get it? @SourabhSomani

Comment: @JamesRiady Check my answer

Comment: **go to the cinema with me?** how can you get this line like you are saying

Comment: I try to use substring but I think that is too static. The point is I want to get like that with using substring. I don't know if it possible or not. That's why I asked here to make sure about it.. or maybe you have your own way, then let me know it @SourabhSomani

Answer (score 2):

You can try like as follows

```js
var arr = ["Hello my name is jimmy", "will you go to the cinema with me?", "who's him?"]
arr.forEach(e => {
   $('#hello').append(e+" ")
})
```

```css
#hello{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="width: 100px" id="hello">
</span>
```

Comment: Do you want like that

Comment: this is not like I want, wait, I will change the question

Comment: @JamesRiady Okay change the question I am not getting you properly

Comment: I have changed the question, the point is
I have to use the `\n`

Comment: Now see my text is justify

Comment: do not need to take substring of 10 characters

Comment: As I understand your question I got you just want to justify the text

Comment: yes only 10 characters, but I want that if the string is only 9 characters, it still display a new line